# Angular File Upload module & Typescript compatibility

Tags: angularjs, typescript

We needed a file upload system in Angular js & typescript that works with a .Net Web api & supports multipart file upload with progress bar indicating % of streaming upload as well as success/failure at server end

I found the ng-file-upload library by Daniafarid, and it works well (I have implemented a sample using 10.1.9 version), a similar working sample can be found @
http://monox.mono-software.com/blog/post/Mono/233/Async-upload-using-angular-file-upload-directive-and-net-WebAPI-service/

I observed the actual sequence of referring the .js files have been suggested as –

```
   'public/lib/ng-file-upload/FileAPI.min.js', 
   **'public/lib/ng-file-upload/angular-file-upload-shim.min.js',**
   'public/lib/angular/angular.js',
   **'public/lib/ng-file-upload/angular-file-upload.min.js',**
```

Now while I can implement the sample using the javascript (.js) version, I am stuck while trying to implement using the available Typescript library.

When I installed the available definitely typed version from Nuget(angular-file-upload.Typescript.DefinitelyTyped) –it seems the library is not compatible with the main library & it gives build error due to mismatch in module and service names like “angular.angularFileUpload” (which we had to edit and make ng.FileUpload or ng.ng FileUpload ).

But even after correcting those, I am unable to load the ngFileUploadModule and keep on receiving the following error –

> Filter   Regex   Hide network messages •  All •  Errors •  Warnings • 
>   Info •  Logs •  Debug •  Handled .
>   1.    angular.js:78 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module main due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to
>   instantiate module ngFileUpload due to: Error: [$injector:nomod]
>   Module 'ngFileUpload' is not available! You either misspelled the
>   module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that
>   you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

It seems that the angular file upload definitely typed library also do not have the shim component viz- “angular-file-upload-shim.min.js” so it also seems the dependencies are not properly registered.

I have also updated the Angular.Typescript.DefinitelyTyped library to the latest version 12/12/2015 from Nuget, but still no result.

Kindly suggest if anyone has any clue as to how to overcome this and load the ngFileUpload module using typescript